# How to change plotting options while using Map

Tags: graphics, plotting

I have multiple series, which I want to plot using ListLinePlot and Map. For example

```
datamatrix = RandomInteger[{1, 9}, {20, 3}];
ListLinePlot /@ Transpose[datamatrix]
```

By doing this, I can plot all three series. I am trying to specify different plotting options for my different graphs. For example, I want to apply different titles (Title1, Title2, Title3 for illustration purpose) and different colors to my graphs (Red,Green and Pink for illustration purpose). If possible, I want to specify different DataRange.

Please, help. Simpler the answer, the better. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
datamatrix = RandomInteger[{1, 9}, {20, 3}];
styles = {Directive[Thick, Red], Directive[Thick, Green],  Directive[Thick, Blue]};
titles = ToString /@ {title1, title2, title3};
ListLinePlot[#, PlotStyle -> #2, PlotLabel->#3] & @@@ 
    Transpose[{Transpose[datamatrix], styles,titles}]
```

[image]

```
ListLinePlot[#, PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Hue[RandomReal[]]]] & /@Transpose[datamatrix]
```

[image]

Comment: @ kguler Thanks. You guys are smart. I always imagine and post a question, somebody like you will answer. Thanks for your contribution to this forum.

Comment: @rka, thank you for the kind words.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach would be to use `MapThread`, which avoids one `Transpose`. I also created the titles a different way using `Array`, purely for didactic purposes of showing how to automate these things. Note that you can avoid using `Directive` in this way by setting `BaseStyle`.

```
datamatrix = RandomInteger[{1, 9}, {20, 3}]; 
colors = {Red, Green, Blue}; 
titles =  Array["Title " <> ToString[#] &, 3]; 
Grid[{MapThread[ListLinePlot[#, PlotStyle -> #2, PlotLabel -> #3, 
     BaseStyle -> Thick] &, {Transpose[datamatrix], colors, titles} ]}, 
     ItemSize -> Full]
```

[image]

Comment: @ Verbeia, thank you for taking time to answer this question.